# SharedPreferences in Non-Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, android-fragmentactivity

Hi I need to get a String from an Activity to another Class. I need the String VideoID in the Test2 class. I wanted to use sharedpreferences, but this does not work. How can i use sharedpreferences here? Or any other idea how i can get the String? Thanks

In my Activity I have this Button:

```
// Video Button
final Button videobutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.videobutton);
videobutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Video ID save
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("VideoID_saver", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("VideoID", current_video);
            editor.commit();

            Intent OpenTest = new Intent(Questions.this, Test2.class);
            startActivity(OpenTest);
        }
    });
```

The Test2.class looks like this:

```js
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class Test2 extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
    public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyCb2pCHbqhBDKaYzFvU7g1SBG14YrM3XWE";

    //Test
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("VideoID_saver", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String testtext = prefs.getString("VideoID", "");

    //http://youtu.be/<VIDEO_ID>
    public final String VIDEO_ID = testtext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test2);

        /** Initializing YouTube player view **/
        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failured to Initialize!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        /** add listeners to YouTubePlayer instance **/
        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
        player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

        /** Start buffering **/
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
        }
    }

    private PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new PlaybackEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {}

        @Override
        public void onPaused() {}

        @Override
        public void onPlaying() {}

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {}

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {}

    };

    private PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new PlayerStateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {}

        @Override
        public void onError(ErrorReason arg0) {}
 
        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String arg0) {}

        @Override
        public void onLoading() {}

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {}

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {}
    };
```

Comment: You need a loadPreferences call to get the SharedPreferences.

Comment: And how das this loadPreferences call look like? I couldn't find something about that

Comment: Eh, never mind.  I misspoke.  I see now that you do have the reading and writing set correctly.  Last time I did this, I wrote a function called LoadPreferences.  But looking at the code, it's essentially the same as what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably somehow accessing different SharedPreferences instances.  It's easier to make sure this doesn't happen using the `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` method:

In you Activity:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
    .edit()
    .putString("VideoID", current_video)
    .apply();
```

In your Test2 `onCreate` method:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String testtext = prefs.getString("VideoID", "");
```

Comment: You forgot to apply your transaction.  `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString("VideoID", current_video).apply();`

Comment: thanks, that wasn't the final solution, but the hint for the "onCreate" Methode was enaugh. SharedPreferences seems to function only in the onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things. Test2 is inheriting an activity it seems, so not sure why your title says Non-Activity. SharedPreferences reading and writing seems ok but maybe reading the sharedpreferences even before the constructor on the activity has had change to run is too early.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to get a string from button to `test2.` It seems like it would be better to avoid shared preferences entirely and pass the string to the next activity directly via the put/getExtra function.

Like so:

```
Intent OpenTest = new Intent(Questions.this, Test2.class);
i.putExtra("VideoID", current_video);
startActivity(OpenTest);
```

Then extract it from your new activity in your `OnCreate` method:

```
//http://youtu.be/<VIDEO_ID>
public final String VIDEO_ID;

@
Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//Test
Intent intent = getIntent();
VIDEO_ID = intent.getExtras().getString("VideoID");

}
```